# Add a node in xml using java only if the node has an attribute

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml code and I want to add a note in node `manufacturedMaterial` only if it has the attribute `determinerCode`.

```
<manufacturedProduct classCode="MANU">
   <manufacturedMaterial classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">
      <code code="10219000" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.1" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="Tablet"/>
      </epsos:code>
   </manufacturedMaterial>
   <manufacturedMaterial classCode="MMAT">
      <code code="10219001" codeSystem="0.4.0.127.0.16.1.1.2.2" codeSystemName="EDQM" codeSystemVersion="2017-04-14" displayName="NoTablet"/>
      </epsos:code>
   </manufacturedMaterial>
   </manufacturedProduct>
```

Currently, my code is the following, but add a new child in both `manufacturedMaterial` nodes. Is there a way to check whether it has the attribute `determinerCode` or not?

```
NodeList nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName("manufacturedMaterial");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        Element formCodeEl = dom.createElement("epsos:formCode");
        formCodeEl.setAttribute("code", myCode.get(i));
        node.appendChild(formCodeEl);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the list of attributes in the node?

```
if(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("determinerCode") != null)
{
    // Add your node here...
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!